# Clear form after user submit

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm using the funcion clearForms to reset my form after submit:

```
<script>
function clearForms()
{
  var i;
  for (i = 0; (i < document.forms.length); i++) {
    document.forms[i].reset();
  }
}
</script>
```

And setting the body to:

```
<body onLoad="clearForms()" onUnload="clearForms()">
```

But this method is from 2006 (http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/clearform.html). Is there a way to do it with jquery?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to clear the form on unload ?! ?!

Comment: If the user clicks back, the form fields would still be remembered. This is a possible solution.

Comment: exactly! Is there a way to disable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
(function() {
    var resetForms = function () {
        $('form').each(function() {
            this.reset();
        });
    };

    resetForms();

    window.onbeforeunload = resetForms;
})();
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @Eli! I'm looking for this all day!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have jQuery included in the page, you should be able to use the following once the page has loaded:

```
$('form :input').val('').html('');
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rjzaworski/qNWKQ/)

Comment: That doesn't reset a select tag

Answer (score 0):

The native script in original post is more efficient performance wise than using jQuery methods, and still as effective as it was years ago.

jQuery uses native javascript methods....it just wraps many of them in a more convenient way to use them with less code

Comment: The solution from @Eli works like a charm. Also, I found this other way too: 
<body onload="document.forms[0].reset();" onunload="document.forms[0].reset();">

Comment: Whatever makes you happy....only point of my post is that although jQuery simplifies a lot of coding....native is faster. I personally write tons of jQuery...not condeming it in any way. Everyone jumped on bandwagon to provide a "jQuery" solutuon per request